# Catching an exception if there's no connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, connection

I've got a website in asp.net / c# that updates an SQL server, which currently is working fair enough. However, I'm looking at taking it onto mobile devices and wondering what to do if the device loses connection. Basically, I'm wanting to catch it if it can't connect when the user tries to make edits.

The basic code is:

```
try
{
    Conn.Open();
}
catch (SqlException)
{
    Session["HaveWeUpdated"] = 0;
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Error')", true);
}
finally
{
    Conn.Close();
}
```

Which should bring up the pop-up message if it can't connect, as well as set our HaveWeUpdated session value to 0. Unfortunately, at the moment, when I try it (simply by pulling the cable out of my PC) it goes to the standard IE8 "diagnose connection problems" page and does NOT show the pop-up message - hence, I guess, it's not being caught.

Comment: The `finally` could throw an exception if you couldn't open the connection. Use the `using` statement to dispose/close the connection.

Comment: is it actually a `SqlException` ? I would be surprised if a network error manifested as `SqlException`. Note: `using` is preferable to `Open`/`Close`. Also: if this is ASP.NET, then your C# code runs *at the server*; the browser dialog runs *at the client*. Different universe (ignore if this is actually mobile device code).

Comment: your problem is related to "diagnose connection problems", Please refer my answer below..

Comment: @TimSchmelter Using statement also does the same. No difference at all. It will throw the exception.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, that is what Tim Schmelter said to do?

Comment: @Chris My point is what is the benefit in doing so? if there is no difference ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: The `using` does not prevent exceptions in general but it avoids that a `finally` throws an exception if you're trying to close a connection there that cannot be closed.

Comment: Because a using ensures that Dispose is called on the connection, whereas, if there was an exception in the finally it would not.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Just tested, calling close on un-opened connection doesn't throw exception

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: as you can see at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close(v=vs.110).aspx) `Connection.Close` can throw a `SqlException`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I suppose documentation is wrong "The connection-level error that occurred while opening the connection." It says when opening a connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about how your web site is working.

The code you have written here, works on the server, not on the mobile device. Thus, it checks whether it can connect to database; it does not check whether you can connect from your mobile device to the website.

Simply, when you put the cable out, the connection between your local machine and the web server is lost.

To clarify more:

1- Web browser requests a page

2- Web server receives the request

3- Web server calls the database server

4- Web server receives the response from DB server

5- Web server processes the response

6- Web server sends the response to the browser

7- Browser processes and displays the response.

Comment: I guess @daryal got it.If your SQL Server instance is on other computer, you may pull the cable out of this one (it's important that the server of your website and of your database are in different machines to test it, otherwise, you can just inform a wrong connection string), and your website you'll be able to retrieve the error/exception to you.

Comment: That makes sense. I had hoped that, as the page is loaded, it would remain in memory and not have to go back and forth between the server for literally everything. In that case, as @daryal says, I guess it wouldn't be possible. Thanks for your answers!